# Create struct depending on other struct member

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct defined with typedef

```
typedef struct 
{
   uint16_t x;
   uint16_t y;
   uint16_t width;
   uint16_t height;
}TArea;
```

Now I want to create some areas that depends on each other.
Something like

**AreaDefs.h**

```
extern TArea UI_AREA_1;
extern TArea UI_AREA_2;
```

**AreaDefs.c**

```
TArea UI_AREA_1 = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .width = 5, .height = 10};
TArea UI_AREA_2 = {.x = UI_AREA_1.x, .y = 200, .width = 5, .height = 10};
```

Why do i get "Error: expression must have a constant value" and whats a better solution? I dotn want to make something like

```
#define X_VAL 0
TArea UI_AREA_1 = {.x = X_VAL, .y = 0, .width = 5, .height = 10};
TArea UI_AREA_2 = {.x = X_VAL, .y = 200, .width = 5, .height = 10};
```

because of in my real application I have more than this two areas that depends on each other.

Comment: The error should really say it all. The initializers of the structure members must be compile-time constants. You can't use other structures members as they are not compile-time constants.

Comment: "*whats a better solution*" -- probably a better *design*, but it's hard to suggest something without knowing more about the current design and the purpose of the application... In general, it's good to have *one* place for a given value.

Comment: Also, even if the two structures shares common values at initialization, they are still not *linked*. If you in code change `UI_AREA_1.x` then `UI_AREA_2.x` will not automatically change.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to have constants in compile time. So I will not change AreaDefinition while runtime. The intention is to create a user interfaace with area defintions and edit only one file to change the gui. So area1 and area2 have same x value. Area3 has x value of Area1+5 , Area4 has same x value like Area3 but other y.. etc.

Comment: In runtime a user pushes a button and i want to create gui with PrintArea(TArea* area)...

Answer (score 1):

When initializing a variable, the initializer cannot be the value of another variable, even if that variable is defined `const`.  It must be a constant value.

The best you can do is what your second example does: use a `#define` to initialize certain variables to the same value.

Comment: @Frank C++ is a completely different language with completely different set of rules. If I recall correctly, C++ had an exception to rules that allowed use in integer expressions.